# How to return Future<File> as File parameter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have this

```
  return Image.file(getImageLink(file));
```

Here the Image.file needs File Parameter

Here is my function

```
  Future<File> getImageLink(Reference ref) async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return File("${dir.path}/${ref.name}");
  }
```

But I ran into this issue

```
Future<File> getImageLink(Reference ref)
Type: Future<File> Function(Reference) package:***/dashboard/home.dart

The argument type 'Future<File>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.
```

Please I need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getImageLink` is a `Future` function you need to `await` for its result:

```
var _file = await getImageLink(file);
return Image.file(_file);
```

if you use this inside build method you need to use `FutureBuilder`:

```
return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: getImageLink(file),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading....');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            } else {
              File _file = snapshot.data!;

              return Image.file(_file);
            }
        }
      },
    ),
```

Comment: I am using this inside itemBuilder(){}

so it is not possible to put async

Comment: @Tpp I updated my answer, check it out.